# javascript how to remove part of the text

Tags: javascript, text

So I have a text like this:

```
["Floor=3r4"][Doors75][Doors25]Red
["Floor=4t3"][Doors45]Blue
["Floor=7t"][Doors56]Green
```

Numbers and letters after "=" can be random.

I want to remove all ["Floor=*"] from this text to get something like this:

```
[Doors75][Doors25]Red
[Doors45]Blue
[Doors56]Green
```

I was playing around with .replace but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Please post what you tried.

Comment: It seems like `.replace` with a regular expression should do exactly what you want. Why didn't it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small change for alphanumeric characters only since you mentioned numbers and letters:

```
var resultString = sampleString.replace(/\["Floor=[a-z0-9]*"]/g,'');
```

Also, i find this site really helpful when it comes to figuring out regex patterns:
http://www.regexr.com/
It helps to test your patterns as you build them on the fly, and also guides you through it! Hope you find it useful.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. A thank you for the link to web site.